# how to collect data from loop

Tags: clojure

hi guys how to collect data from if condition in a loop

```
(defn update-f [a b]
 (let[data(loop [i 0]
         (when (< i (count a))
           ;;(println i)
            (if (every? (set b) (nth (for [x a]  (set (list x))) i))
                    (nth (for [x a]  (conj x "new")) i)
                    (nth (for [x a]  (conj x "old")) i))
           (recur (inc i))))])); loop i will take this value
```

i can print data from if condition i need take data from this function

Comment: What data do you need to "take"?  Also, it would be helpful if you would add some example input and what the expected output would be.

Comment: input (def a (list [22 23 24] [23 25 26] [27 23 24]))
(def b (list [22 23 24] [23 25 26]))
output  (core/update-f a b)
           [22 23 24 new]
           [23 25 26 new]
           [27 23 24 old]
nil

Comment: @gokul, you should edit your question and add the example there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can collect data in a loop by adding an extra "accumulator" parameter:

```
(loop [i 0 acc []]
  (if (< i 5)
    (recur (inc i) (if (even? i) 
                       (conj acc i)
                       acc))
    acc))
```

However, it seems that what you are trying to achieve could be written much more concise (if I got what you want right):

```
(defn are-new? [a b]
  (map (fn[i] [i (if (b i) :new :old)]) a))
```

We are mapping every item in `a` to add a `:new` or `:old` tag to it. A set also acts as a function, that returns a truthy value when the argument exists in the set. So to find if an item `i` is already in set `b`, we can simply do `(b i)`.

And you can test it:

```
(let [r (are-new? [[1 2 3] [2 3 4] [1 2]] #{[1 2 3] [1 2]})]
  (doseq [i r]
    (println i)))

> [[1 2 3] :new]
> [[2 3 4] :old]
> [[1 2] :new]
```